# Steam Android App Doesn't Open Steam Game Page Via Link

Tags: android, flutter, steam

Hİ I have a mobile app that lists steam games. When I click the game It asks me to open with Steam android app or browser. When I select the steam app in a second it shows a blank screen and turns back my app again. I test it with other app links like Github it is working. So how can I open the Steam game in the Steam app via the link.

Comment: Btw I am using flutter launchurl